# Robôzinho para monitorar preços

Tags: php, robots.txt

Certa vez em uma aula o professor comentou que ele programou um "robôzinho" pra acompanhar certas informações de um site. Ele captava o código fonte de certa página e com funções dentro da linguagem conseguia captar o que ele precisava e exibia somente essas informações. Preciso fazer o mesmo, estou trabalhando autônomo de revenda de celulares na OLX, quero programar um programinha em php, que eu já tenho um certo domínio, ou outra linguagem que se adaptaria melhor ao problema, pra carregar a página que preciso, retornar os dados dos celulares que virão de acordo com as variáveis que eu desejar (ex: titulo, preço, data e filtro de valor) e exibir na tela pra mim. Tudo isso pensando em praticar o meu algoritmo, aprender uma coisa nova e já também servir de utilidade pro meu trabalho. Faço engenharia da computação e estou em busca de vários desafios.

Desde já, obrigado, pra resumir, quero orientações do que pesquisar pra aprender isso e conseguir andar com minhas próprias pernas a partir dai, sair do "zero".

Answer (score -1):

Fernando, eu acredito que você consiga encontrar programas que já fazem isso que você quer para a OLX.

Se ainda quiser construir o seu próprio você vai precisar criar um programa que age um pouco como um navegador (chrome, firefox...). Seu programa vai precisar fazer chamadas de POST e GET no site da OLX e interpretar o retorno das chamadas.
Uma maneira de pesquisar como fazer isso é aprendendo a interagir com REST API. A diferença é que você vai usar o site da OLX como se fosse uma API.
Depois que você conseguir obter todas as informações você vai ter que interpretar tudo que conseguir para exibir (ou armazenar).